# Sorting array by common fields (javasciript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects and I want to sort it by common types.
Some objects have types with 'x', some with 'y' and some with 'z'.

For now, I'm able to sort it and put all the 'x' in front. However, I would want to do the same for 'y', and 'z' too.
In the end, all 'x' would be in front, then all 'y' and then 'z'.

```
list.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type !== b.type) {
      if (a.type === 'x') { return -1; } 
      return 1;
    }  
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: please add some data to sort and the wanted result as well.

Comment: Are you always wanting to sort `type` alphabetically ascending? Or is x, y, z, coincidental?

Comment: @mhodges Not alphabetically. Just according to the common fields.

Comment: I got that you're wanting to sort according to the `type`. How do you want them displayed? For example, what if you had a `type == "w"`.. would that always go before `x`? Or are you trying to arbitrate a sort priority that is non-alphabetical?

Comment: @mhodges Oh, so x, y, z, is coincidental and later on I would want to decide whether I want to put new type like "w" before or after x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to define a numeric order for the types and use the classic approach to sort an array of objects by a numeric property:

```js
var order = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}
var data = [
  {type: 'z'},
  {type: 'y'},
  {type: 'x'},
  {type: 'x'},
  {type: 'y'},
  {type: 'z'}
]

var sortedData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return order[a.type] - order[b.type]
})

console.log(sortedData)
```

Note that you may want to include some error handling, e.g. for types which are not maintained in the `order` map.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a really elegant and simple solution. It worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for `type` with the sort order.

```js
var list = [{ type: 'a', name: 'z' }, { type: 'b', name: 'a' }, { type: 'c', name: 'b' }, { type: 'x', name: 'c' }, { type: 'x', name: 'd' }, { type: 'y', name: 'e' }, { type: 'y', name: 'f' }, { type: 'z', name: 'g' }, { type: 'z', name: 'h' }, ]

list.sort(function (a, b) {
    var order = { x: -1, y: -1, z: -1, default: 0 };
    return (order[a.type] || order.default) - (order[b.type] || order.default) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

It works with

> ```
> {
>     f: -2,         // top
>     x: -1,         // \
>     y: -1,         //   a group after top
>     z: -1,         // /
>     default: 0     // a default value for not mentioned types for sorting in the middle
>     a: 1           // after the common parts
>     d: 2           // bottom
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But for some reason it doesn't for me. I tried the solution from another user and it works. Thank you for posting :)